# Can the rip, tide, car-ry me home?

Tags: opening

[Event "Hourly Bullet Arena"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/klfXSKWU"]
[Date "2024.03.28"]
[White "NileshMondal"]
[Black "healLan"]
[Result "0-1"]
[UTCDate "2024.03.28"]
[UTCTime "07:01:25"]
[WhiteElo "1426"]
[BlackElo "1447"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "-8"]
[BlackRatingDiff "+5"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "60+0"]
[ECO "B50"]
[Opening "Sicilian Defense: Modern Variations"]
[Termination "Time forfeit"]
[Annotator "lichess.org"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 { B50 Sicilian Defense: Modern Variations } 3. d3 Nf6 4. Nc3 g6 5. Bg5 Bg7 6. Bxf6 Bxf6 7. Be2 O-O 8. Qd2 Nc6 9. O-O Bg7 10. Rab1 e5 11. Nd5 Be6 12. Qc3 Bxd5 13. exd5 Nd4 14. Nxd4 cxd4 15. Qd2 Qf6 16. c4 b6 17. Qb4 Qd8 18. a3 a5 19. Qb3 Qc7 20. Bf3 Qc5 21. Rfe1 Rae8 22. Qb5 Qxb5 23. cxb5 Rc8 24. a4 Rc2 25. b3 Rfc8 26. Red1 f5 27. h3 e4 28. dxe4 fxe4 29. Bxe4 Re2 30. Bf3 Ree8 31. Kh2 Rf8 32. Re1 Rf4 33. Re6 Rcf8 34. Rxd6 R8f6 35. Rd8+ Rf8 36. Rxf8+ Bxf8 37. Kg3 Bc5 38. Kxf4 d3 39. Rd1 d2 40. Rxd2 Bb4 41. d6 Bxd2+ 42. Ke4 Bb4 43. d7 Be7 44. Ke5 Bd8 45. Ke6 Kf8 46. Bc6 g5 47. g4 h6 48. Kf5 h5 49. Kg6 h4 50. Kh5 Ke7 { Black wins on time. } 0-1